# Apache Commons CLI allow argument option or no argument option

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

Simply, I am wondering if it is possible to have an argument accept an option or accept no option. This is useful for listing. Example: `-a` will list possible options while `-a stuff` will use that stuff to do things.

Here is my current code:

```
options.addOption("f", "look-and-feel", false, "This sets the look and feel.");
//Some stuff happens here
if (cmd.hasOption('f')) {
    String laf = cmd.getOptionValue('f');
    System.out.println(laf);
    if (laf == null) {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            System.out.println(info.getClassName());
        }
        return;
    } else {
        setLookAndFeel(laf);
    }
} else {
    setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
}
```

Typing `-f` lists the look and feels correctly, while specifying it `-f com.laf.LookAndFeel` still lists it. Any ideas?

Comment: I added the code I am using that does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your option, use this instead:

```
Option lookAndFeelOption = new Option("f", "look-and-feel", true, "This sets the look and feel.");
lookAndFeelOption.setOptionalArg(true);
options.addOption(lookAndFeelOption);
```